# Override taxonomy_term_uri

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to modify the behavior of `taxonomy_term_uri()` in a custom module for D7? I am not able to do so by definining `THEME_term_uri()`, and I wouldn't like to alter the original Taxonomy module.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to alter URLs for some terms that so they point to existing pages. I needed to create a tree-like menu structure, but due to a requirement for every item to contain custom fields, I couldn't use the menu, but resorted to a vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to override it. I found out that `'taxonomy_term_uri'` is defined in **taxonomy.module**'s `taxonomy_entity_info()` function, so I added a hook that alters it:

```
function MODULE_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {  
    $entity_info['taxonomy_term']['uri callback'] = 'MODULE_taxonomy_term_uri';
}

function MODULE_taxonomy_term_uri($term) {
    // change the path...
    return array(
        'path' => 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`taxonomy_term_uri()` is called from [entity_uri()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_uri/7), which contains the following code.

```
 // Invoke the callback to get the URI. If there is no callback, return NULL.
  if (isset($uri_callback) && function_exists($uri_callback)) {
    $uri = $uri_callback($entity);
    // Pass the entity data to url() so that alter functions do not need to
    // lookup this entity again.
    $uri['options']['entity_type'] = $entity_type;
    $uri['options']['entity'] = $entity;
    return $uri;
  }
```

The value returned from `entity_uri()` is normally passed to [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7). This means that implementing [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7), and [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) could achieve the same result as implementing [hook_entity_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) to change `$entity_info['taxonomy_term']['uri callback']`, even though `hook_entity_info_alter()` is more easily implemented. I would probably implement the first two hooks if I need to alter the URI for more than one entity.

`hook_url_outbound_alter()` would get the entity type, and the entity object as `$options['entity_type']`, and `$options['entity']`.
`hook_url_outbound_alter()` and `hook_url_inbound_alter()` would also work with modules that don't use `entity_uri()` to get the entity URI; in that case, `hook_url_outbound_alter()` cannot probably count on `$options['entity_type']`, and `$options['entity']` being set.